# Using trait methods from a structure implementation

Tags: rust

I want to use a trait in Rust like an interface.

```
struct CPU {
    r: u32,
    pc: u32
}

trait Bus {
    fn read(&self, address: u32) -> u32;
    fn write(&self, address: u32, data: u32) -> u32;
}

impl CPU {
    fn step() {
        let opcode = self.read(0xffff);   // use Bus trait method here
    }
}
```

I need to know how to use the trait methods within my implementation of CPU without implementing read or write inside my CPU implementation. I'd like to have those in another file as they will define the memory map. I feel like this is a simple problem, I just can't find the answer that works for me.

Comment: It is **highly suggested** that you read the **excellent** [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/) which covers a lot of these introductory questions. This is covered in the [traits chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html).

Comment: I have read the first edition of the book, didn't realize there was a 2nd edition, I'll have to read it as Rust has changed a bit since I last used it. I guess my main issue is with switching from inheritance based languages to Rust's composition based design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trait implementations are always in their own `impl` block.

```
impl Bus for CPU {
    fn read(&self, address: u32) -> u32 { unimplemented!() }
    fn write(&self, address: u32, data: u32) -> u32 { unimplemented!() }
}
```

A little known trick is that `impl` blocks can be written in any module in your crate, so long as both the trait and the type are visible to that module (the module that contains the `impl` doesn't have to be public). If the implementation is going in a submodule under the module that defines `Bus` and `CPU`, then the submodule will automatically have access to both types. Otherwise, you'll need to add `pub(crate)` (or some other form of `pub` that works for you) on either or both declarations. Naturally, you may need to `use` the trait and the type to bring them in the scope of the module that contains the `impl`, or use qualified paths.

For example, if you want to put the `impl` in a submodule, you could write either:

```
use super::Bus;
use super::CPU;    

impl Bus for CPU {
    fn read(&self, address: u32) -> u32 { unimplemented!() }
    fn write(&self, address: u32, data: u32) -> u32 { unimplemented!() }
}
```

or

```
impl super::Bus for super::CPU {
    fn read(&self, address: u32) -> u32 { unimplemented!() }
    fn write(&self, address: u32, data: u32) -> u32 { unimplemented!() }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I took a break from Rust and was having trouble with this. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what I was trying to do.

```
// bus controls reads and writes to/from emulated cpu
// a trait allows me to define the interface the cpu expects
pub trait Bus {   
  fn read(&self, size: Size, address: u32) -> u32;
  fn write(&self, size: Size, address: u32, data: u32);
}

// must have an object to implement the bus on
pub struct Mem {}  // this can be filled out later

// implement Bus trait for our Mem
impl Bus for Mem {
  fn read(&self, size: Size, address: u32) -> u32 { unimplemented!() }
  fn write(&self, size: Size, address: u32, data: u32) { unimplemented!() }
}

// here is our cpu struct with a generic Bus trait object in it
pub struct M68K<A: Bus> {
  pub d: [u32; 8],
  pub a: [u32; 8],

  pub x: bool,  // extend
  pub n: bool,  // negative
  pub z: bool,  // zero
  pub v: bool,  // overflow
  pub c: bool,  // carry

  pub bus: A    // here is the Bus trait object
}

// when we implement our cpu we can use the Bus trait methods, this allows
// multiple cpu's to be created with the same or different Bus objects. 
// possibly connect 2 cpu's to the same Bus object?
impl M68K<Mem> {
   pub fn step(&self, cycles: u32) {
     let x = self.bus.read(Size::Byte, 0xffff);
  }
}
```

This code is not finished. My main goal is to create an easy to use 68k cpu emulator for my own projects. Here I show everything in one file, but in reality the entire cpu emulator can now be written without any knowledge of our the Bus is implemented. I hope this makes sense, it does to me and I'm enjoying Rust again!